# Can a matrix factorization algorithm be guaranteed to converge to a global minimum?

Tags: recommender-system

Collaborative filtering is a common technique used by recommender systems. Matrix factorization is a common way to do collaborative filtering.

The problem of matrix factorization for recommender systems can be stated as follows:

> Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^{u \times i}$ be a matrix of user-item ratings. Hence there are $i$ items and $u$ users in total. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ be a positive integer denoting the latent factors we want to get.
>
> Find $U \in \mathbb{R}^{u \times n}$ and $I \in \mathbb{R}^{i \times n}$ such that $||R - U \cdot I^T||$ is minimal.

I think that all matrix factorization algorithms initialize $U$ and $I$ randomly and converge to a local minimum.

Is that always the case? **Is there a property of the problem which makes it impossible that an algorithm is guaranteed to find a global minimum?** Can one make a statement about how likely it is that a minimum is found? Is there any stability criterion about the latent factors?